# How to animate a Path around a circle?

Tags: wpf, animation

WPF

The following code correctly draws a Path with center point at (560,200). The Path consists of two arcs. The outer arc of radius 150 and an inner arc with radius 100:

```
<Grid Margin="0,-2,0,2">
    <Path x:Name="FlyingArc" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
                Data="M 710,200               
                A 150 150 0 0 0 666.0660,93.9340                
                L 630.7107,129.2893              
                A 100 100  0 0 1  660,200               
                z" 
                Fill="Green" Stroke="Black">

        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="noFreeze" />
        </Path.RenderTransform>

        <Path.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Path.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"
        To="-360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Path.Triggers>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that rotating the Path this way results in a rotation with radius 560.

I would like to rotate the Path, "FlyingArc" around the inner circle of radius 100 with center point at (560,200). That is to say, I want all points of the FlyingArc path to remain equal distant from the center of the rotation--that center being at 560,200 with a radius of 100.

How is that done?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Path element should have a fixed `Width` and `Height` of 300, and the `Data` should be adjusted so that it is centered at (150,150). You may then use an appropriate `Margin` to move it to the desired location.

Note also that the parent Grid adjusts the layout position of the Path. It is stretched by default, which effectively makes it centered when it has a fixed size. Perhaps use a different `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`, or a `Canvas` parent.

```
<Path x:Name="FlyingArc"
      Width="300" Height="300"
      Margin="410,50,0,0"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
      Data="M300,150
            A150,150,0,0,0,256.0660,43.9340                
            L220.7107,79.2893
            A100,100,0,0,1,250,150Z" 
      Fill="Green" Stroke="Black"
      RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
```

---

In order to avoid any issues with clipping, you may as well animate the `Transform` property of the Data Geometry instead of the `RenderTransform` of the Path:

```
<Path x:Name="FlyingArc"
        Width="300" Height="300"
        Margin="410,50,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Fill="Green" Stroke="Black">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="M300,150
                               150,150,0,0,0,256.0660,43.9340                
                               L220.7107,79.2893
                               A100,100,0,0,1,250,150Z">
            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                <RotateTransform CenterX="150" CenterY="150"/>
            </PathGeometry.Transform>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data.Transform.Angle"
                        To="-360" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Path.Triggers>
</Path>
```

Comment: Man your good! If you only knew how long I've worked on this! Thanks :)

Comment: Please see the edited answer for a slightly better solution.